# R for loop in parallel

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I want to run for loop in parallel threads.

My dataset is from the stock market and is of the form:
`Type ID Token Buy/Sell Price Quantity`

Type is:
`N` for New Order
`M` for Modifying an Order
`X` for cancelling an order
`T` for an order that has being traded

`ID` is a sixteen digit unique number corresponding to a particular order.It is generated when a `New Order` comes. It is required when an order is being `Modified`, `Cancelled` or `Traded`.

`Token` corresponds to different companies in the stock market. They are 5 digit numbers.

A `Trade` message is a bit different. Its of the form:
`Type BuyOrderID SellOrderID Token Price Quantity`

The four types are as follows:

```
N   1200000000006773    48256    B  13595   4000
M   1200000000006773    48256    B  13585   4000
X   1200000000006649    48331    B  70125   500
T   1200000000009326    1200000000007756    48321   7275    8000
```

Now I want to parse through each row, store the tokens in a hashtable, and go on with the corresponding actions.

I have more than a billion rows, so I need parallel processing for faster results. How to change the for loop (no matter using what) to make use of parallel processing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059). You need to seriously investigate if you can't avoid an R-level loop. I seriously doubt that parallelization alone (even using a large number of CPUs) will help with your performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `parallel` library:

```
library(parallel)
cores.number <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores.number, type = "FORK")
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, iseed = seed)
```

And then use `parLapply`, `parSapply` etc like this:

```
parSapply(cl, X, function)
```

Check the package documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

Comment: The `parallel` package now belongs to the R base library. Provided that the installed `R` version is up-to-date, the most recent documentation is available with `vignette("parallel","parallel")`.